# Update structure JavaFX TreeTableView

Tags: javafx

I create two windows and pass the Instance controller to the child window as a parameter. My problem is updating on the fly. I tried calling the refresh() method on treeTblState but nothing came of it.

First window

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mo.specdoc.controllers.StateController">
   <children>
      <TreeTableView fx:id="treeTblState" showRoot="false">
        <columns>
          ....
        </columns>
      </TreeTableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller

```
public class StateController implements Initializable {
    private static Map<Long, TreeItem> subdivisions = new HashMap<>();
    private static StateController instance;
    @FXML    private TreeTableColumn<StateEntity, String> tblClmnTitle,...,tblClmnDelete;
    @FXML    private TreeTableView<StateEntity> treeTblState = new TreeTableView<>();
    //Create root element (property setShow = false в FXML)
    private StateEntity root = new StateEntity(0L,"State");
    //Pattern Instance
    public static StateController getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new StateController();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            tblClmnTitle.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("postName"));
            ...
            tblClmnDelete.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("delete"));
            treeGreate();
        } catch ....
    }

    public void addChildren(StateEntity state) {
        TreeItem<StateEntity> item = null;
        for (Long key : subdivisions.keySet()) {
            if (key == state.getSubdivisionId()) {
                TreeItem<StateEntity> subdiv = subdivisions.get(key);
                item = new TreeItem<StateEntity>(state);
                subdiv.getChildren().add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void treeGreate() {
        TreeItem<StateEntity> itemRoot = new TreeItem<StateEntity>(root);
        treeTblState.setRoot(itemRoot);
        //create tree - level 2
        //subdivisions
        for (SubdivisionEntity subdivision : subdivisionDAO.findAll()) {
            StateEntity state = new StateEntity(
                    subdivision.getId(),
                    subdivision.getTitle()
            );
            state.getAdd().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    createScene("Add post", new StateEntity(), subdivision.getId());
                }
            });
            TreeItem<StateEntity> subdiv = new TreeItem<StateEntity>(state);
            itemRoot.getChildren().add(subdiv);
            subdivisions.put(state.getSubdivisionId(), subdiv);
            //posts
            List<StateEntity> childrens = stateDAO.findByIdSubdiv(state.getSubdivisionId());
            if (!childrens.isEmpty()) {
                for (StateEntity child : childrens) {
                    TreeItem<StateEntity> item = new TreeItem<StateEntity>(child);
                    subdiv.getChildren().add(item);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void createScene(String title, StateEntity state, Long subdivisionId) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/state-edit.fxml"));
            StateEditController stateEditController = new StateEditController(state, subdivisionId);
            loader.setController(stateEditController);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.showAndWait();
        } catch ....
    }
}
```

Second window

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      ...elements...
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller

```
public class StateEditController implements Initializable {
    ....

    @FXML
    void saveAction(ActionEvent event) {
        currentEntry.setSubdivisionId(subdivisionId);
        currentEntry.setMaxAmountPersonal(cmbBoxMaxAmount.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().intValue());
        currentEntry.setMinAmountPersonal(cmbBoxMaxAmount.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().intValue());
        currentEntry.setAmplification(tglSwitchAmpl.isSelected());
        currentEntry.setPostId(cmbBoxPost.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId());
        if (currentEntry.getId() == null) {
            stateDAO.save(currentEntry);
        } else {
            stateDAO.update(currentEntry);
        }
        stateController.addChildren(currentEntry); //call instance metod
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Result

[image: result window 2]

Everything is entered into the database successfully, but it is not updated when the window is closed 2.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: _I tried calling the refresh() method on treeTblState_ - would be the wrong approach: refresh is emergency api for extremely rare corner cases, seeming to be needed is an indication of incorrect setup between data and view.

Answer (score 0):

I redraw the child elements using the clear method when adding an item

```
public void addChildren(StateEntity state) {
        subdivisions.get(state.getSubdivisionId()).getChildren().clear();
        List<StateEntity> childrens = stateDAO.findByIdSubdiv(state.getSubdivisionId());
        if (!childrens.isEmpty()) {
            for (StateEntity child : childrens) {
                TreeItem<StateEntity> item = new TreeItem<StateEntity>(child);
                subdivisions.get(state.getSubdivisionId()).getChildren().add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm .. answer or clarification of question? If the former, explain how it solves the problem, if the latter, edit the question to include it) Either way, the question should contain a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected :)

Comment: kleopatra, sorry, i rewrote the method addChildren from the question. This solution